# How to call LsaRemoveAccountRights in c++

Tags: c++, windows, security, winapi, visual-c++

I'm trying to create a code such that I, the administrator, can't shut down the computer. I'm learning and this is something that is easy to see whether it works. The problem is that I get an unhandled exception from within LsaRemoveAccountRights. I got most of the code from a japanese site but all examples do pretty much the same. So why doesn't mine work?

```
// This is how I call the function
bool f = DelRights(SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME, true);

bool DelRights(wchar_t *szPrivilege, bool bRevoke)
{
    LSA_UNICODE_STRING Rights = {0};
    LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES Attr = {0};
    SECURITY_QUALITY_OF_SERVICE Quality = {0};
    bool bRet = false;

    DWORD SidSize = SECURITY_MAX_SID_SIZE;

    Rights.Buffer = szPrivilege;
    Rights.Length = wcslen(szPrivilege) * sizeof(WCHAR);
    Rights.MaximumLength = (wcslen(szPrivilege) + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR);


// Allocate enough memory for the largest possible SID.
    PSID AdminSID = LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED, SidSize);

    if (AdminSID) {
        ::SecureZeroMemory(AdminSID, SidSize);

        if (CreateWellKnownSid(WinBuiltinAdministratorsSid, NULL, &AdminSID, &SidSize)) {
            LSA_HANDLE hPolicy = 0;


            Attr.Length = sizeof(Attr);
            Attr.RootDirectory = NULL;
            Attr.ObjectName = NULL;
            Attr.Attributes = 0;
            Attr.SecurityDescriptor = NULL;
            Attr.SecurityQualityOfService = &Quality;

            Quality.Length = sizeof(Quality);
            Quality.ImpersonationLevel = SecurityImpersonation;
            Quality.ContextTrackingMode = SECURITY_DYNAMIC_TRACKING;
            Quality.EffectiveOnly = FALSE;

            if (ERROR_SUCCESS == LsaOpenPolicy(NULL, &Attr, POLICY_ALL_ACCESS, &hPolicy)) {
                NTSTATUS status = 0;

                if (bRevoke) {
                    status = LsaRemoveAccountRights(hPolicy, AdminSID, FALSE, &Rights, 1);

                    if (ERROR_SUCCESS == status) {
                        bRet = true;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    status = LsaAddAccountRights(hPolicy, AdminSID, FALSE, 1);

                    if (ERROR_SUCCESS == status) {
                        bRet = true;
                    }
                }

                LsaClose(hPolicy);
            }
        }

        GlobalFree(AdminSID);
    }

    return bRet;
}
```

Comment: When I read the documentation again for LsaOpenPolicy, it said that all members of LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES could be set to 0. I'm not sure about the length member. I still get the same problem

Comment: I have made some progress. It turns out the sid was the problem. I changed code such that the sid is created by                                           if (AllocateAndInitializeSid(&SIDAuthNT, 2, SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID, DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &AdminSID)) {

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a PPSID (`PSID*`) to `CreateWellKnownSid` while it is awaiting **only** a `PSID`. This doesn't crash here because I guess the pointer get dereferenced only later in `LsaRemoveAccountRights`.

Correct code should be:

```
PSID AdminSID = LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED, SidSize);

if (AdminSID) {
    ::SecureZeroMemory(AdminSID, SidSize);

    // pass AdminSID, not &AdminSID
    if (CreateWellKnownSid(WinBuiltinAdministratorsSid, NULL, AdminSID, &SidSize))
```

Comment: Thank you. I get no errors. The only problem is that it doesn't seem to have any effect. I can still shut down the computer. Isn't it supposed to take effect immediately? Maybe I'm using the wrong sid? It should be the sid for the currently logged on user.

Comment: Finally, the code works. It's just that I have to restart before it takes effect. Is there something that can be done such that it takes effect immediately?